# How to determine if a vertex can be reached in a directed graph using breadth first search

Tags: c++, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

When trying to determine if a vertex in a directed graph is reachable, I use breadth first search to traverse the graph from the my source vertex to the destination vertex. However, when I compare what I pop off the queue during bfs (which should be every vertex I have visited) it is only returning false and never in any instance true despite me knowing that the graph can return true in some instances, can some help me out?

here is my code

```
    template <typename E> 
bool Graph<E>::isReachable(E fromKey, E toKey) const
{

   Edge* tmpEdge;
   Edge* pred;
   Edge* edgeWalk; 
   Vertex* walkPtr;
   Vertex* toPtr; 
   Vertex* tmp;
   Vertex* tmpFrom;
   Vertex* tmpTo;
   queue<Vertex*> q;

   /* find source vertex */
   tmpFrom = first;
   while (tmpFrom != NULL && fromKey > tmpFrom->data)
      tmpFrom = tmpFrom->pNextVertex;
   if (tmpFrom == NULL || fromKey != tmpFrom->data)
      return false;
   /* locate destination vertex */
   tmpTo = first; 
   while (tmpTo != NULL && toKey > tmpTo->data)
      tmpTo = tmpTo->pNextVertex;
   if (tmpTo == NULL || toKey != tmpTo->data)
      return false;

  walkPtr = first;
   while (walkPtr != NULL)
   {
      walkPtr->processed = 0;
      walkPtr = walkPtr->pNextVertex;
   }
   walkPtr = first;
   while (walkPtr != NULL)
   {
      if (walkPtr->processed < 2)
      {
         if (walkPtr->processed < 1)
         {
            q.push(walkPtr); 
            walkPtr->processed = 1;
         }
      }
      while (!q.empty())
      {
          tmp = q.front();
          q.pop();
          tmp->processed = 2;
          edgeWalk = tmp->pEdge; 
          while (edgeWalk != NULL)           
          {
              toPtr = edgeWalk->destination;
              if (toPtr->processed == 0)
              {
                  toPtr->processed = 1;
                  q.push(toPtr);
              }
              edgeWalk = edgeWalk->pNextEdge;
          }
          if (tmpTo->processed = 2)
              return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your vertex list properly sorted?  If it isn't (as appears likely), you'll fail to find the from or to keys and return false.  And I say "likely", because there are several problems with your loop at the bottom, one of which (`tmpTo->processed = 2`; you should use `==`) will cause the function to return true all the time.

Comment: my code to find the to and from vertex works properly and is tested in other instances in the program

Comment: @NicholasCharles Then fall back on the tried-and-true method of stepping thru it in your debugger.